# macOS Maps - any way to change the default starting point for navigation?

Tags: macos, defaults, maps

Is there a hidden setting to change the default starting point for Maps navigation away from "My Location"?

**The Problem:** When I'm traveling, I frequently want to check the distance between two locations in a distant place (hotel to attraction or restaurant). Every time I find the destination and click on "Directions", Maps immediately starts getting Navigation directions from my "Current Location" which wastes time and data usage because the map zooms out and away, starts looking for multiple routes, and runs into a dead end if there is an ocean in-between. Tedious to click in the Start box and delete "My  Location" each time.

I could find nothing obvious in the output of: 
`defaults read "com.apple.Maps"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable "Your Location " for Map

[image]

Then you would get this in Map ..

And have to enter the Starting and the End points

[image]

Comment: If you liked it check m answer, so other can find it as helpful.